# Manipulate expression giving error messages

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, warning-messages

I'm trying to debug this example code from a textbook:

```
Manipulate[
  (*Evaluate Eq.(8.2)*)
  hh = 1/Sqrt[(1 - (r Ω0) ˆ2) ˆ2 + (2 ζ r Ω0) ˆ2];
  thh = ArcTan[1 - (r Ω0) ˆ2, 2 ζ r Ω0];
  (*Obtain coefficients from either Eq.(8.5) or Eq.(8.6)*)
  cnn = 
    If[ptyp == 1, 
      Abs[Sin[r π α]/(r π α)], 
      a1 = (2 Sin[2 π α r] - Sin[4 π α r])/(π r);
      b1 = (1 - 2 Cos[2 π α r] + Cos[4 π α r])/(π r);
      Sqrt[a1ˆ2 + b1ˆ2]];
  psnn = 
    If[ptyp == 1, 
      ArcTan[1 - Cos[2 r π α], Sin[2 r π α]], 
      ArcTan[b1, a1]];
  ptin = Table[{n, cnn[[n]]}, {n, 1, nn}];
  ptout = Table[{n, hh[[n]] , cnn[[n]]}, {n, 1, nn}];
    lines = 
      Table[
        {{n, 0}, {n, If[cnn[[n]] < hh[[n]] cnn[[n]], hh[[n]] cnn[[n]], cnn[[n]]]}}, 
        {n, 1, nn}];
  (*Sum series:Eq.(8.1)*)
  xt = 
    If[ptyp == 1, 
      α + 2 α Total[cnn hh Sin[r Ω0 t - thh + psnn]], 
      Total[cnn hh Sin[r Ω0 t - thh + psnn]]];
  (*Coordinates to draw pulse*)
  If[ptyp == 1, 
    pulse1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 0}};
    pulse2 = {{2 π/Ω0, 0}, {2 π/Ω0, 1}, {π α/Ω0 + 2 π/Ω0, 1}}, 
    pulse1 = 
      {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, -1}, {4 π α/Ω0, -1}, 
       {4 π α/Ω0, 0}};
    pulse2 = {{2 π/Ω0, 0}, {2 π/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0 + 2 π/Ω0, 1}}];
  (*Create two graphs,one above the other*)
  GraphicsColumn[
    {Plot[xt, {t, -π/Ω0/5., 2 π/Ω0 + π α/Ω0}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
       PlotRange -> {Full, {-2, 2.3}}, 
       PlotLabel -> label1, 
       AxesLabel -> {"τ", "Amplitude"}, 
       Epilog -> {{Blue, Line[pulse1]}, {Blue, Line[pulse2]}}], 
     ListLinePlot[lines, PlotStyle -> Black, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, nn + 1}, Full}, 
         PlotLabel -> label2, 
         AxesLabel -> {"n=Ωn/Ω0", "Magnitude"},
         Epilog -> 
           {{Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[ptin]}, 
            {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[ptout]}}]}],
  (*Create sliders and radio buttons*)
  Style["Periodic Waveform", Bold], 
  {{ptyp, 1, " "}, {1 -> labs, 2 -> labd}, ControlType -> RadioButton}, 
  Delimiter, 
  Style["Input Parameters", Bold], 
  {{Ω0, 0.04, "Ωo"}, 0.01, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}, 
  {{α, 0.2, la}, 0.02, 0.49, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}, 
  Delimiter, 
  Style["Damping Factor", Bold], 
  {{ζ, 0.1, "ζ"}, 0.02, 0.7,0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}, 
  Delimiter, 
  Style["Frequency Spectrum -", Bold], 
  Style[" Maximum Number of Harmonics Displayed", Bold], 
  {{nn, 20, "N"}, 1, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  Initialization :> (
    puls = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.25, 1}, {0.25, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.1, 1}};
    (*Radio button images*)
    labs = 
      ListLinePlot[puls, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-0.1, 1}}, 
        Axes -> False, 
        ImageSize -> Tiny, 
        Epilog -> 
          {Arrowheads[0.1], 
           Arrow[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}], 
           Arrow[{{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}], 
           Inset[Style["2π/Ω0", 14], {0.5, 0.65}], 
           Inset[Style["τd", 14], {0.125, 0.1}]}];
     puld = 
       {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.15, 1}, {0.15, -1}, {0.3, -1}, 
        {0.3, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.1, 1}};
     labd = 
       ListLinePlot[puld, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-1.1, 1}}, 
         Axes -> False, 
         ImageSize -> Tiny, 
         Epilog -> 
           {Arrowheads[{-0.1, 0.1}], 
            Arrow[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}], 
            Inset[Style["2π/Ω0", 14], {0.5, 0.75}], 
            Inset[Style["τd", 14], {0.075, 0}]}];
     (*Figure titles*)
     label1 = 
       Column[
        {"Time Domain Waveforms", 
         Row[{Style["Input, ", Blue], Style["Output ", Red]}]}, 
        Center];
     label2 = 
       Column[
         {"Frequency (Harmonic) Spectrum", 
          Row[{Style[Row[{"Input cn"}], Blue], 
          Style[Row[{" Output [cnH(Ωn)]"}], Red]}]}, 
         Center];
     (*Slider label*)
     la = "α=Ωoτd/(2π)"; 
     r = Range[1, 150];), 
  TrackedSymbols :> {Ω0, α, ζ, nn, ptyp}]
```

The purpose for this code is to represent Periodic Force on a Single Degree-of-Freedom System.

Among this huge block, there is an issue with the plot elements representing this engineering problem. There is an error that says the following:

> Coordinate {1, (0.008 $CellContext`ˆ2 + (1 - 0.04 $CellContext`ˆ2) $CellContext`ˆ2)^Rational[-1, 2], 0.9354892837886392} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Can anyone help me find the bug that's causing the titles in the graph figures to not come out properly?

Comment: That’s a lot of code to wade through! What steps have you taken to debug it yourself? You are asking somebody to do a lot of work on your behalf which, once done, will be of no benefit to anyone but you, since it’s highly unlikely that another user will have the same problem with the same code again in the future...

Comment: Take a look at `ptout`.  It has 3 coordinates, but it should have only 2.  Also, some of your exponent symbols (^) are not the right character.  The clue is that the "2" that follows them is blue instead of black.  Also, the wrong characters are smaller than the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  hh = 1/Sqrt[(1 - (r Ω0)^2)^2 + (2 ζ r Ω0)^2];
  thh = ArcTan[1 - (r Ω0)^2, 2 ζ r Ω0];
  If[ptyp == 1,
    cnn = Abs[Sin[r π α]/(r π α)];
    psnn = ArcTan[1 - Cos[2 r π α], Sin[2 r π α]],
    a1 = (2 Sin[2 π α r] - Sin[4 π α r])/(π r);
    b1 = (1 - 2 Cos[2 π α r] + Cos[4 π α r])/(π  r);
    cnn = Sqrt[a1^2 + b1^2];
    psnn = (Quiet @ ArcTan[b1, a1] /. Indeterminate -> 0.)];
  ptin = Table[{n, cnn[[n]]}, {n, 1, nn}];
  ptout = Table[{n, hh[[n]]}, {n, 1, nn}];
  lines =
    Table[
     {{n, 0},
      {n, If[cnn[[n]] < hh[[n]] cnn[[n]], hh[[n]] cnn[[n]], cnn[[n]]]}},
   {n, 1, nn}];
  xt =
    If[ptyp == 1,
      α + 2 α Total[cnn hh Sin[r Ω0 t - thh + psnn]],
      Total[cnn hh Sin[r Ω0 t - thh + psnn]]];
  If[ptyp == 1,
    pulse1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 0}};
    pulse2 = {{2 π/Ω0, 0}, {2 π/Ω0, 1}, {π α/Ω0 + 2 π/Ω0, 1}}, 
    pulse1 = 
      {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0, -1},
       {4 π α/Ω0, -1}, {4 π α/Ω0, 0}};
    pulse2 = {{2 π/Ω0, 0}, {2 π/Ω0, 1}, {2 π α/Ω0 + 2 π/Ω0, 1}}];
 
  GraphicsColumn[
    {Plot[xt, {t, -π/Ω0/5., 2 π/Ω0 + π α/Ω0},
       PlotStyle -> {Red},
       PlotRange -> {Full, {-2, 2.3}},
       PlotLabel -> label1,
       AxesLabel -> {"τ", "Amplitude"},
       Epilog -> {{Blue, Line[pulse1]}, {Blue, Line[pulse2]}}],
     ListLinePlot[lines,
       PlotStyle -> Black,
       PlotRange -> {{0, nn + 1}, Full},
       PlotLabel -> label2,
       AxesLabel -> {"n=Ωn/Ω0", "Magnitude"},
       Epilog ->
         {{Blue, PointSize[Medium], Point[ptin]},
          {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[ptout]}}]}],
 
  Style["Periodic Waveform", Bold],
  {{ptyp, 1, " "}, {1 -> labs, 2 -> labd}, RadioButton},
  Delimiter,
  Style["Input Parameters", Bold], 
  {{Ω0, 0.04, "Ωo"}, 0.01, 1, 0.01, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{α, 0.2, la}, 0.02, 0.49, 0.01, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Delimiter,
  Style["Damping Factor", Bold],
  {{ζ, 0.1, "ζ"}, 0.02, 0.7, 0.01, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Delimiter,
  Style["Frequency Spectrum -", Bold],
  Style[" Maximum Number of Harmonics Displayed", Bold], 
  {{nn, 20, "N"}, 1, 50, 1, Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  ControlPlacement -> Left,
 
  Initialization :> (
    puls =
      {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.25, 1}, {0.25, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.1, 1}};
    labs =
      ListLinePlot[puls,
        PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-0.1, 1}},
        Axes -> False,
        ImageSize -> Tiny,
        Epilog ->
          {Arrowheads[0.1],
           Arrow[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}],
           Arrow[{{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.5}}],
           Inset[Style["2π/Ω0", 14], {0.5, 0.65}],
           Inset[Style["τd", 14], {0.125, 0.1}]}];
    puld =
      {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0.15, 1}, {0.15, -1}, {0.3, -1}, 
       {0.3, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1.1, 1}};
    labd =
      ListLinePlot[puld,
        PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-1.1, 1}},
        Axes -> False,
        ImageSize -> Tiny,
        Epilog ->
          {Arrowheads[{-0.1, 0.1}],
           Arrow[{{0, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}],
           Inset[Style["2π/Ω0", 14], {0.5, 0.75}],
           Inset[Style["τd", 14], {0.075, 0}]}];
    label1 =
      Column[
        {"Time Domain Waveforms",
         Row[{Style["Input, ", Blue], Style["Output ", Red]}]},
        Center];
    label2 =
      Column[
        {"Frequency (Harmonic) Spectrum",
         Row[
           {Style[Row[{"Input cn"}], Blue], 
            Style[Row[{" Output [cnH(Ωn)]"}], Red]}]},
        Center];
    la = "α=Ωoτd/(2π)";
    r = Range[1, 150]),
 
  TrackedSymbols :> {Ω0, α, ζ, nn, ptyp}]
```

[image: demo]

#### Notes

1. Replaced bad unicode characters in the expressions for `hh` and `the` with `^`.
2. Rewrote expression fro `pout` to produce array of pairs rather than triples. This suppresses the error message that the OP reported.
3. Revised the calculation of `psnn` so it doesn't complain about indeterminate values returned by `ArcTan`.

Comment: I have learned my lesson: Don't copy and paste code off a pdf